# Chrome Image Preloading does not work on first image load

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, preloading, image-preloader

I have anchors on a page that displays a different background image on mouse hover and mouse out. I have preloaded the images to avoid flickering and re-requesting the images from the server on mouse hover/out. The scripts works fine on IE8/FF but Chrome behaves differently. In the latest version of Chrome, the first time I hover on the anchor, the image is re-requested from the server causing a flicker, why is this? Succeeding mouse hover/out works fine and there is no flicker.

Code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
body:after
{
  content: url('/images/1.png') url('/images/1a.png')
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.imageHover
{
   display:inherit;
   width:25px;
   height:50px;
   background:url('/images/1.png') no-repeat;
}

.imageOut
{
   display:inherit;
   width:25px;
   height:50px;
   background:url('/images/1a.png') no-repeat;
}
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var oneSelected = new Image();
    var oneUnselected = new Image();

    oneSelected.src="/images/1.png";
    oneUnselected.src="/images/1a.png";

    function OnImageMouseOver(target) {
       $(target).toggleClass('imageHover', true);
       $(target).toggleClass('imageOut', false);
    }
    function OnImageMouseOut(target) {
       $(target).toggleClass('imageHover', false);
       $(target).toggleClass('imageOut', true);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" class="imageOut" onmouseover="OnImageMouseOver(this)" onmouseout="OnImageMouseOut(this)"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Converted anchor to image, but it still won't work in Chrome:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
    if (document.images) {
        var oneSelected = new Image();
        var oneUnselected = new Image();

        oneUnselected.src = '/images/1a.png';
        oneSelected.src = '/images/1.png';
    }

    function OnRatingMouseOver(target, newSrc) {
        $(target).attr('src', newSrc);
    }

    function OnRatingMouseOut(target, newSrc) {
        $(target).attr('src', newSrc);        
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv" style="width:400px;">
      <div id="inputDiv">
         <table id="inputTable">
            <tr>
               <td>Rating</td>
               <td>
                  <img id='rating1Anchor'
                        src='/images/1a.png'
                        onmouseover="OnRatingMouseOver(this, '/images/1.png');"
                        onmouseout="OnRatingMouseOut(this, '/images/1a.png');"
                        onclick="OnRatingClick(this, '/images/1.png', 1);">
                  </td>
           </tr>           
         </table>
      </div> 
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: This is odd. I just tried it on Chrome on my home PC and it's working just fine (images are not being re-requested from the server). Can anybody shed light on this?

Comment: To add some context, the page I am creating is a SharePoint WebPart on a custom page. It appears that the image response headers are playing part in the way Chrome behaves.

Comment: Some more info: Tested in IE9 and Opera and the images aren't re-requested. In Chrome, the issue seems to be intermittent. On a newly opened tab, the images are re-requested. But opening a new tab on the same window, the images aren't re-requested. Clicking refresh button on the new tab again re-requests the images on hover and mouse out.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. What was the outcome?

Comment: I've examined the requests - the only difference is that the second request has a cookie not present in the first.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be preloading them at all, as it's not displaying them it's just adding to the DOM? Try the following code to preload your images.

```
var preload = new Array();

function preload_image(){
    for (var x = 0; x < preload_image.arguments.length; x++)
    {
        preload[x]     = new Image();
        preload[x].src = preload_image.arguments[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is displaying the image as the css class of the anchor is initially set to "imageOut".

Answer (score -1):

I have to say I very much doubt that the pngs are actually being rerequested from the server in Chrome. Can you post a screenshot of the Timeline in dev Tools showing the request going off twice? :) I think it's far more likely that you're just experiencing a slight hesitation during the repaint.

Is there a reason you aren't using image sprites? They are the canonical solution to this problem. The idea is simply that a single image is loaded that contains both the normal and "hover" or "active" states. The portion of the graphic shown gets swapped out using css "background-position". Here's a [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), and here's a [table of support](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y) for "background-position" which goes all the way back to IE4.

Code should look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    #myCoolLink {
        background-image:url('img/image.gif');
        background-position:0px 0px;
    }
    #myCoolLink:hover,
    #myCoolLink.active {
        background-position:0px -72px; //depending of course on the image
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" id="myCoolLink"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

No script required, and it's much terser. The other great advantage of this is that you can still programmatically change the image over to the "hover" anytime you want by toggling the "active" class on the link, if you ever need to.

Comment: Why the downvote? Care to explain? Please show me the network pane with the request for the exact same image firing twice :)